# What causes SFML pollEvent to segfault here?

Tags: sfml, c

I'm writing an SFML application in C. Currently `sfRenderWindow_pollEvent()` and `sfRenderWindow_waitEvent()` always segfault.

Here's the cleaned code that shows the issue.

```
sfRenderWindow* window;
sfVideoMode mode = {SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 32};
window = sfRenderWindow_create(mode, "SFML window", sfResize | sfClose, NULL);

sfEvent* InputEvent;

while(1)
{
    while (sfRenderWindow_pollEvent(window, InputEvent) == sfTrue) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize your `InputEvent` pointer. Currently you only declare the pointer with `sfEvent* InputEvent;`, so there is actually no memory allocated for the event.

You need to either change the line to `sfEvent InputEvent;` and change the while-loop to `while (sfRenderWindow_pollEvent(window, &InputEvent) == sfTrue)`, or you can manually allocate space for the event by calling `InputEvent = malloc(sizeof(sfEvent));`

Comment: Yes, this works

Comment: Please accept the answer and feel free to leave an upvote too. I'm happy I could help.